# "Meta-artifact" on Gradle

Tags: virtual, gradle, meta, artifact

I have a project that publishes two artifacts to a Maven repo with Gradle.

I would like to publish a third "empty" artifact that could serve as a meta/virtual package for the other two, so that any other project could reference just the meta artifact as a dependency and get the two real dependencies.

Is this possible? I couldn't find anything similar to what I need in the docs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven BOMs aren't currently supported by Gradle. You might be able to publish one, but consuming it from Gradle won't have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if this is something that will be available in the future? Or some way to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: I'd expect BOMs to be supported at some point, but I can't make any promises. To share dependency declarations between Gradle builds, you can write a script plugin or binary plugin. I don't know of a feasible way to consume BOMs.